# Firebase admin get file from Storage with temporary download url

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I am trying implement a function which provides a temporary file url for downloading. Right now user enter his/her email id and function response with a file url. To fetch the file I am using firebase-admin SDK to access storage bucket and retrive a file.

**Problem :** Right now everything is working fine but the file URL is not working.. I am getting the error: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.

```
app.post('/getFile', (req, res) => {
        let email = req.body.mail;
        if (micro.validateEmail(email)) {
            micro.checkIfUserExists(admin, email)
                .then(data => {
                    storage.file('form.pdf')
                        .getMetadata()
                        .then(fileRes => {
                            sendMail.send(email, fileRes[0].mediaLink).then(msg => {
                                res.send({
                                    uri: fileRes,
                                    res: msg,
                                    mail: email,
                                    data: data
                                })
                            });
                        });
                });
        }
    });
```

**Edit:**

So I have found that I could use getSignedURL to get a url but I don't know how to specifiy a file path, for which I url is needed.

```
const bucket = storage.bucket();

//-
// Generate a URL that allows temporary access to list files in a bucket.
//- 

const config = {
  action: 'list',
  expires: '03-17-2025'
};
 
//-
// If the callback is omitted, we'll return a Promise.
//-
bucket.getSignedUrl(config).then(function(data) {
  const url = data[0];
});
```

**Edit 2**

So I have found that you can specify the file by specifying the bucket.file('')

```
const bucket = storage.bucket().file('form.pdf');
```

But now I have another problem.  I am getting this error in firebase function log

```
Permission iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob is required to perform this operation on service account
```

Comment: You need to either specify a service account explicitly in the code, or grant the default GCF service account the signBlob permission indicated in the error message. You can do so by granting the "Service Account Token Creator" role to the default service account.

Comment: Yes I resolved all the issues by genereating service account credential in firebase and passed it into initialized()